# Saving many images with its dynamic name

Tags: c++, image

I need to save images captured from camera just like 
"D:\storage\img1" then I press "s" another time and program should save 
"D:\storage\img2" and then 
"D:\storage\img3"
so everytime I press a custom key it will save an image with different name.
How to do that?

Thanks for all your responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code concatenates (adds) the  value of `int i` to  `string filename`.  This is done through  `IntToStr()`   .  And `int i` loops from `0`  to  `20` and thus  creating your "dynamic name".

File output :

PhotoImage0.txt 
PhotoImage1.txt 
PhotoImage2.txt 
.. 
.. 
PhotoImage19.txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string IntToStr(int n) 
{
    stringstream result;
    result << n;
    return result.str();
}

int main () 
{
    ofstream PhotoImageFile;
    int Number_of_files=20;
    string filename;


  for (int i=0;i<Number_of_files;i++)
  {
        filename="c:\\PhotoImage" + IntToStr(i) +".txt";
        cout<< filename << "  \n";

        PhotoImageFile.open(filename.c_str());
        PhotoImageFile << filename<<" : Writing this to a file.\n";
        PhotoImageFile.close();
  }


  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On startup, iterate the folder with an 'img*.*' mask - how you do this is up to your file system API.  Use string functions or a loop to extract the part of the filename representing the number and convert it to an int.  Every time you need to save a file, add 1 to the int, convert back to number-string & then concat the path, "img", number-string and extension to assemble the new file spec.